# rails "Toggle!" not working as its supposed to work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
     def apply
      @role.toggle!(:filled)
      if @idea.save
         redirect_to ideas_path, notice: 'Role was successfully updated.' 
      else
         flash[:alert]= 'please login first'
         redirect_to login_path
      end
  end
```

So i am trying to toggle the field "filled" but it says "undefined method `toggle!' for nil:NilClass". Any help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `@role` object must be an activerecord object and the error clearly says that it's `nil`.

Comment: Do you mean i should instantiate it or do you mean the method itself should be in the model? im sorry i did not understand you comment properly.

Comment: You are calling a method `@toggle!` on an object, `@role`, right? That method is available only if `@role` is not nil and is an activerecord object. Can you check why `@role` is nil? and put a check to not toggle if object is nil.

Comment: ah now i get you.I will try doing that. Thanks so much!